# Unity: Android logcat spammed by "addLayerName, tid: 17835" message

Tags: unity-game-engine, logcat

I'm trying to debug my Unity Android app, but the logcat is spammed with the above mentioned message. I cannot see where in the code this line is produced. Probably something internal to Unity (!)?

Does anyone know where this message comes from and how to switcht it off?

Comment: I know how to filter logcat, however, I'm looking for the reason why Unity outputs these messages and then turn off the cause. It might also lead to a bigger issue (could impact performance of the app for example)

Comment: Same thing here. I need help with this.

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm not using Unity, but cocos2d-x. Added a bounty in case it helps.

Answer (score -1):

The "addLayerName" message is internal and generated by Unity's graphics system. It's related to the rendering process like the `addLayerName` is suggesting, and is typically not an indication of a larger problem, although every situation is unique.

It most likely appears in the logcat output when Unity adds or updates a layer name for a specific thread ID (tid).

I recommend a debugging walkthrough of your code and checking for places where you suspect this might occur, that is, inspecting the code that relates to working with (updating) layers, experimenting a bit with commenting it out, and trying to invoke the log yourself to identify how (and why) it works.

That includes any references to `LayerMask`, `LayerMask.NameToLayer`, `LayerMask.GetMask`, or `GameObject.layer` properties, etc.

Comment: If none of that helps, I'd give the profiler a go as well.

Comment: As indicated in a comment to the question, I do have this spammy log in my apps as well, while I'm NOT using Unity.

Comment: It’s likely for similar reasons and if the message looks the same it could be in relation to both engines supporting OpenGL ES. If you’re not experiencing any unusual behavior, it’s safe to assume that the log message is pretty harmless and unlikely an indication of large underlying issue. As previously mentioned, best bet is debug walkthrough the code and paying close attention to the logcat